# android - pass value back to the same activity on a button click and refresh the page

Tags: android, callback

I need to pass a value back to the same activity and refresh the activity to generate new data. Can anyone please provide me some ideas/guidance on how to do it? Thank you.
I had try using intent to call the same activity but it doesn't work. Here is the code which i tried to use intent:

```
btn_next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                page_counter = page_counter + 1;
                if (page_counter > 1){
                        btn_prev.setEnabled(true);
                }
                 Intent i = new Intent();
                 i.setClassName("sample.android.androidgallery","helloAndroid");
                 i.putExtra("page",wallpaper_page_counter); //to pass this activity's data to next
                 startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: In what way did using the Intent not work?

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to update the contents of an activity by re-launching the same activity with a different intent instead of just doing it directly?

Comment: if i commented the startActivity(i); then there were no error but if i include it then it will prompt an alert box stating that the application had been stopped unexpectedly. Force close.

Comment: yup. i try to re launch the same activity with a different intent as i do not know how to do it directly. Is there any other way that i can do to get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putXXX(key,value);

intent.setClassName(MainActvity.this,MainActvity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```